# Android Content Providers - INSERT with a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I am using Android's content providers as a wrapper around an SQLite3 database. It's never been my choice to use content providers for stand alone app centric databases due to the limited flexibility and bloat they can cause. However I'm working on a pre-existing code base. I need to write an **insert** **query** with a **WHERE NOT EXISTS clause**. However, I see that the insert command of the ContentProvider only permits a URL (which I used to identify the table) and a ContentValues object containing the data to insert as a new row.

Is there any way to do a this, or something that is in effect the same, without manually performing essentially an inefficient checking select query before the insert for checking purposes?

I don't want to modify the DB table structures or constraints as there are to many dependencies which may break with alterations.

Comment: What's an `INSERT...WHERE` look like, and what is it supposed to do? I'm not aware of SQL that supports that. Or are you looking for `INSERT...SELECT`?

Comment: Ok I have clarified what I mean by updating my question. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So you're looking for `INSERT OR IGNORE` in sqlite. In `SQLiteDatabase`, that's wrapped in `insertWithOnConflict` with `CONFLICT_IGNORE`. You could expose that in a `ContentProvider` by convention, unless you need to modify that behavior for any reason.

Comment: Ok, so thanks for the terminology that's good, but how do I do this with the ContentProvider of Android?